# Rspecでテストを実行しようとすると ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)と出てくる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

現在Twitterライクなアプリケーションを作っています。
ユーザーは投稿をし、その投稿にコメントをすることができるといったものです。
今回のエラーはコメントをする際に発生します。

Rspecを実行した際のエラー

```
  1) CommentsController POST #create parameter is reasonable is registered
     Failure/Error: post :create, params: { user_id: user.id, post_id: post.id, comment: valid_attributes }, session: {}

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
     # ./spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb:67:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb:66:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

関連するコードは以下のようになっています。

comments_controller_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe CommentsController, type: :controller do
  let(:user) {
    FactoryBot.create(:admin_user)
  }

  before do
    log_in user
  end

  let(:post) {
    user.posts.create(FactoryBot.attributes_for(:post))
  }

  let(:valid_attributes) {
    FactoryBot.attributes_for(:comment)
  }

  describe "POST #create" do
    context "parameter is reasonable" do
      it "is registered" do
        expect {
          post :create, params: { user_id: user.id, post_id: post.id, comment: valid_attributes }, session: {}
        }.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "redirect post page" do
        post :create, params: { user_id: user.id, post_id: post.id, comment: valid_attributes }, session: {}
        expect(response).to redirect_to post
      end
    end
 end
end
```

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.post = @post

    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = 'success in commenting'
      redirect_to post_url(params[:post_id])
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

factories/comments.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :comment, class: Comment do
    content 'a' * 140
    user
    post 
  end
end
```

comments_controller#createにブレークポイントを設定してもデバッガが起動しないことからそれより前でエラーが起きてると思います。

情報量が少なくて申し訳ありませんが、もし似たような事例を経験したことある方がいらっやいましたら、お聞かせください。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

スタック・オーバーフローえようこそ！ `let(:post)`を書いたら、`Rspec`の`post`が上書きしちゃった。`let`で他のヴァリアブルを使うとできる。

Comment: 仰る通り、変数名を変えたらテスト通りました！親切に教えてくださり、ありがとうございました！